# Dynamically incremented property for IEnumerable collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a collection that gets arbitrarily sorted based on conditions. My class has an "Ordinal" int property that I would like dynamically populated after the collection gets ordered. Here is what I have so far:

```
var result = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var x in items)
{
  x.TestA = x.TestA;
  x.TestB = x.TestB;
  x.TestC = x.TestC;
}
...
var ordered = result.AsEnumerable();
if (...) ordered.OrderBy(x => x.TestA);
else if (...) ordered.OrderBy(x => x.TestB);
else if (...) ordered.OrderBy(x => x.TestC);
...
return ordered.ToList()
```

Before returning the ordered list, what is the best way to populate the "Ordinal" property of the "MyClass" objects in the collection with its index location? I am reluctant to create another loop at the end since I have thousands of records. Is this the only way? Thanks for any help or advise.

Comment: `OrderBy` (as well, as other `Enumerable` methods, which return `IEnumerable<T>`) does not affect source sequence. Your code will always return unordered sequence. Also, `List<T>` already is `IEnumerable<T>`, hence, `result.AsEnumerable()` is superfluous. You need something like `IEnumerable<MyClass> ordered = result; if (condition1) ordered = ordered.OrderBy(x => x.TestA); // else if (...) etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any other way then iterating over sorted collection again. You can use LINQ to make it look better, but it will still make an iteration internally:

```
return ordered.Select((x, i) => { x.Ordinal = i; return x; }).ToList()
```

*It will only work if your `MyClass` is really a reference type (`class`).*